# Auto prepend @{user} when comment notifications are auto generated

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, comment-replies, automatic-edits

If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is forgotten.  *From: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)*

This is good, but it's not clear to many users that this is happening and new users might not realize they need to add an @ since it sends replies anyway in this case.

Could **@{user}** be prepended to the comment when notifications are generated automatically?

Comment: Hmmm... there might be an issue with max comment length, but in principle I think this is a great idea.

Comment: @Jon, I agree there would be an issue, but I think it would be rare that anything critical would be lost if the end of a comment at the max was truncated.  Btw, thanks for the edits!

Comment: Don't you think such a user is going to be utterly mystified that a @user appeared out of nowhere?  He'll try to edit it a dozen times to get rid of it.  There's little value.

Comment: @Hans, well prepend it the first time, but don't for edits. I think it is more clear what is happening if you prepend the user than if you show nothing to the user and send a notification anyway.

Comment: Fix for the comment length issue: if the resulting length with the @ name would exceed the max length, then don't include the name. This would probably be a rare case anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't going to happen, since the opposite was implemented (unnecessary `@foo`s are stripped now)